# I Have Been Serial Serial-Down-Voted; What (if Anything) Should I Do?

Tags: support

I have been serial down voted twice in the last three days; first times 5 (although it is possible that a 6th was missed in the roll back) two days ago, and then times 3 today. I have a strong suspicion as to the identity of the perpetrator.

Clearly the individual (a single individual if my suspicions are correct) is persevering in this activity.

Is there any action I should (or can) take?

Comment: Its happened to me, and I generally just laugh. The downvoter loses nearly as much rep as I do from their pique, and I generally have way more rep to spare than they do.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Generally agreed - but if this happens a third time it seems appropriate to bell the cat, for the sake of the community.

Answer (score 5):

If the pattern persists, you can bring the matter to the attention of the mods by flagging one of the post that you suspect to have been targeted. If you think you know who is doing it, you can also put that in the flag message.

But generally there isn't a lot that can be done.

Comment: The system also has an [automated process](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) that may recognise and correct patterns of voting abuse. Otherwise, flagging it for moderator attention is the way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't the automated system pick up 8 downvotes in two days? If the five downvotes on the 1st day all happened within a short space of time, it should be a clear indicator that someone is being targeted.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Yes, the system has reversed those 8 votes. But moderators are not automatically notified when it happens, so we wouldn't know to do anything if the user doesn't bring the issue up directly.